# What is the difference between "Reference" in MOF 1.4 and ECore?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, meta-object-facility

What is the difference between "Reference" in MOF 1.4 and ECore ? MOF has also the "Associations", which can express the same if I understand it right.